# The system file cannot be specified

Tags: c++

I have been trying to output a code for a project, and have tried going through some of the other questions to try resolving the error I am getting which is listed in the title, however I am not getting anywhere with it. Please be as specific as possible, I'm a novice with coding and only know some C++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    //Initialize Variables for initial Lattice
    int Size = 0;
    float Density = 0.0;


    //Input Desired Lattice Size
    std::cout << "How large do you want the square lattice to be? "; cin << Size;

    //Input Desired Density
    std::cout << "What density would you like to test for Percolation? "; cin << Density;

    //Construct Matrix
    float Lattice[Size][Size];
    for (int i = 0; i < Size; ++i)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<Size; ++j)
        {
            Lattice[i][j] = float((int rand() % Size) / (Size));
        }
        std::cout << endl;
    }
    std::cout << Lattice[Size][Size];
    system("pause");
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: OK - don't put two statements on one line! (It's legal, but it's strange.) You've got `cin << Size;` when you need `cin >> Size;`.

Comment: And you've got a stray `int` and an extra half a dozen `(` and `)` - try `Lattice[i][j] = float(rand() % Size) / Size;`.

Comment: While you're at it, turn up your compiler warnings. Variable-length arrays (VLAs) are not C++ standard. Also, even if you do use them (don't btw), your final `std::cout` insertion invokes *undefined behavior* by breaching your array dimensions.

Comment: Replace `float Lattice[Size][Size];` with `vector<vector<float>> Lattice (Size, vector<float>(Size));` and add `#include <vector>`

Comment: Delete `std::cout << Lattice[Size][Size];` - this is an error. The last cell is at [Size-1][Size-1]. Instead, use "range-based for": `for(auto row : lattice){for (auto cell : row) {cout << cell << " ";} cout << endl;}`

Comment: It's also unusual to capitalise variable names. Capitalisation usually indicates `const` values or names of classes. I've put all these suggestions into this [online compiler session](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/6FWKkknqO0OeI9at) if it's useful!

Comment: [rand()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/rand/) function is in `<cstdlib>`. Also, if you want to do type casting in C++, you can do it as in this example, `(float) ((int) rand() % Size) / Size`

Comment: Compile with all warnings & debug info (e.g. `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g` if using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...). Improve your code till you get no diagnositcs (no errors and no warnings). Then **use the debugger** (`gdb`) to run your program step by step.

Comment: You are getting the error message in the title when you do what?

Comment: `float Lattice[Size][Size];`is very suspicious and probably wrong. Standard C++11 does not have [VLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array)s.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you haven't successfully built your application so it doesn't exist.
(The actual error message is "The system cannot find the file specified".)

There are several compilation errors:

`cin << Size;` should be `cin >> Size;`, and the same for the other input line.
(This is easier to spot if you write on separate lines.)

`int rand()` should be just `rand()`.

And variable-length arrays are not standard C++.

There are also a couple of logical errors.

Since `rand() % Size` is less than `Size`, `(rand() % Size) / Size` will always be zero.
(This is an integer division.)

Use `Lattice[i][j] = (rand() % Size) / static_cast<float>(Size);` instead.

Also, I suspect you think that `std::cout << Lattice[Size][Size];` will print the entire array.
It won't; it indexes outside of the array in order to access one `float` and is undefined.
You need to write a loop.

Comment: The `rand()` statement is a C-style cast to float, or trying to be! With some parentheses removed it works.